# JEditorPane component text alignment and background

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcomponent, jeditorpane

[image: GUI with 2 JEditorPane Components]

Hey All, I have two `JEditorPane` in my GUI, from the image the two with `hyperlinks`. Although in `NetbeansIDE` I align them together, the page `editorpane` appears to be shifting right everytime and its pretty annoying. I'm also trying to remove the pointless white background but failing.

Here's some setup for them:

```
        private void initEditorPane(JEditorPane editorPane) {
        editorPane.setBorder(null);
        editorPane.setContentType("text/html");
        editorPane.setEditable(false);
        editorPane.setOpaque(false);
        editorPane.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
            @Override
            public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
                if (e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
                    launchHyperLink(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I am not sure if it's the above causing the problems, or this:

```
pageTxtComp.setText("<html>&nbsp;<a href='" + ac.getPage() + "'>" + ac.getPage() + "</a>&nbsp;</html>");


emailTxtComp.setText("<html>&nbsp;<a href='mailto://" + ac.getEmail() + "'>" + ac.getEmail() + "</a>&nbsp;</html> ");
```

1. How can I improve the alignment?
2. How can I remove the white background? In Properties, I've tried choosing a matching background colour with panel, does not do the trick.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the editor pane itself (ie. the code you posted is not related to the problem). It would be a problem with the layout manager. I don't use an IDE to create forms so I'm not sure what your problem would be. Maybe the IDE is inserting an invisible component before the editor pane. Or maybe you've somehow changed a property in the IDE that is causing the editor pane to be right aligned.

Answer (score 1):

You can get `Document` from the pane. Cast it to `StyledDocument` and use `setParagraphAttributes()` setting desired alignment or change alignment by adding < p > < / p > tags specifying the alignment there.

For background try to set opaque to false for the pane.

Comment: opaque is false already both on properties toolbar as well as in the code, still coming up.